# Table for drawing a game

Tags: tables, game-tree

I am trying to write a table to show the following game. But whatever I do, doesn't work. Can someone help please?

[image]

I don't care about the colors. All in black is fine.

I also would like its variant where T,M,B and L,C,R are in the table, i.e., is in boxes.

This is the code I have attempted, and it doesn't quite produce what I want.

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|}
         & &  \multicolumn2c{Player 2} \\
        %& \multicolumn2c{} & \multicolumn1c{$p$} & \multicolumn1c{$1-p$} \\
        \cline{3-5}
        && L & C & R \\
        \cline{2-5}
        \multirow2*{Player 1} &T & (1,7)
        & (1,1) & (7,0)\\
        \cline{2-5}
        & M & (5,3) & (7,4) & (5,1)\\
        \cline{2-5}
        & B & (3,0) & (6,5) & (6,0)\\
        \cline{2-5}
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the `nicematrix` package, in particular the `first-row` and `first-col` options

Comment: Please make it a habit to provide code we'd like to see here, e.g. by just following these simple steps: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 . Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a couple of `\multicolumn{1}{}{}` to suppress the vertical lines. No need for `\multirow`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &                     \multicolumn{3}{c}{Player 2}                      \\
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{L} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{R} \\ \cline{3-5}
            &          T           &         (1,7)         &         (1,1)         &         (7,0)         \\ \cline{3-5}
   Player 1 &          M           &         (5,3)         &         (7,4)         &         (5,1)         \\ \cline{3-5}
            &          B           &         (3,0)         &         (6,5)         &         (6,0)         \\ \cline{3-5}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|}
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{}   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Player 2} \\ \cline{3-5}
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &   &   L   &   C   &      R       \\ \cline{2-5}
                        & T & (1,7) & (1,1) &    (7,0)     \\ \cline{2-5}
         Player 1       & M & (5,3) & (7,4) &    (5,1)     \\ \cline{2-5}
                        & B & (3,0) & (6,5) &    (6,0)     \\ \cline{2-5}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Player 2} \\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{L} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{R} \\
      \cline{3-5}
      \multirow3*{Player 1} &T & (1,7)
      & (1,1) & (7,0)\\
      \cline{3-5}
      & M & (5,3) & (7,4) & (5,1)\\
      \cline{3-5}
      & B & (3,0) & (6,5) & (6,0)\\
      \cline{3-5}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Player 2} \\
    \cline{2-5}
    & & L & C & R \\
    \cline{2-5}
    \multirow3*{Player 1} & T & (1,7)
    & (1,1) & (7,0)\\
    \cline{2-5}
    & M & (5,3) & (7,4) & (5,1)\\
    \cline{2-5}
    & B & (3,0) & (6,5) & (6,0)\\
    \cline{2-5}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```